# Lucene Stopword and nGram

Tags: java, lucene, tokenize, n-gram, stop-words

I'm using Lucene and I want to use nGrams with stopwords.

I wrote an own Analyzer in Lucene with respect to the German Stopword Analyzer.

```
public class GermanNGramAnalyzer extends StopwordAnalyzerBase {

    @Override
    protected TokenStreamComponents createComponents(String s) {
        NGramTokenizer tokenizer = new NGramTokenizer(4,4); //Tokenizer for nGrams
        TokenStream result = new StandardFilter(tokenizer);
        result = new LowerCaseFilter(result); 
        result = new StopFilter(result, this.stopwords);
        result = new SetKeywordMarkerFilter(result, this.exclusionSet);
        result = new GermanNormalizationFilter(result);
        result = new NumberFilter(result);
        return new TokenStreamComponents(tokenizer, result);
    }
(...)
}
```

This works but not like I want. 
As you can see we have 4 grams so it looks like this: (blanks are masked as "_")

**Das Haus** 

das_
as_h
s_ha
_hau
haus

In German "das" is like "the" and should be removed. But of course it won't be removed then "das_", "as_h", "s_ha" doesn't contains "das" at all.

So I want to first a word tokenizer, use stopword and after that merge everything again and use ngram like normal.

Of course I can "manually" remove all stopwords from the string before I throw it into Lucene but I thought it should be possible to do this with Lucene.

Someone has an idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the possibility would be instead of using **NGramTokenizer** as a tokenizer, first you could use **StandardTokenizer** or any other nice tokenization and then apply creation of the ngrams via usage of **NGramTokenFilter** which could be applied exactly after the usage of StopFilter.